# How to write a samplest kafka spout with New Kafka Consumer API?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, producer-consumer, kafka-consumer-api

Likes storm-kafka-client,I was used storm-kafka-client but cannot work well,and write a new spout not work too.
Who can help me to write a samplest kafka spout.

Answer (score 0):

Define Topology.java

```
import storm.kafka.BrokerHosts;
import storm.kafka.KafkaSpout;
import storm.kafka.SpoutConfig;
import storm.kafka.StringScheme;
import storm.kafka.ZkHosts;

public class Topology{
  public static void main(String[] args){
     TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
     String zkHosts = StringUtils.join("127.0.0.1", ',');

        BrokerHosts hosts = new ZkHosts(zkHosts);
        SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(hosts, "kafkaTopic_name", "/kafkaTopic_name", "kafkaGroup_name");
        spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
        spoutConfig.forceFromStart = forceFromStart;
        builder.setSpout("events", new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig), 5).setNumTasks(5);
        //...
  }
}
```

Basically, you need to create SpoutConfig in order to create kafkaSpout.

Comment: Maybe I make you confuse,but I need that is KafkaSpout.java,not Topology.It is what you new .